# Android - Google play service : Fallback issue

Tags: android, google-play-services, packet-loss

The "Google Play Services" library contains an integrated fallback system in case of lost packets?

Here is the problem. I have a app that works like this:

1. The player A sends a [reliable message](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer#sending_game_data) to the player B
2. The player A can not send another message as long as the player B has not returned a callback via a [reliable message](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer#sending_game_data).
3. If the callback takes too long or is negative, the game is disconnected.

Thereby I ensure that the game always remains synchronized.

The problem is that sometimes, when the connection is poor, the player B's game get suddenly a few steps back (usually 3 to 5).
The interesting thing is that this application has no methods to get back this way, and that it remains connected after this, although it's out of sync.

I have found nothing in the official documentation.
Did one of you already experienced this issue?